# php how to refer to variable in a ORDER BY FIELD()

Tags: php, mysql

I need to dynamically order a table using a variable.

A var_dump of an instance of the variable $vid is:

```
string(9) "15,251,21"
```

And this is an example of the query:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vcomp ORDER BY FIELD(version_id,$vid)");
```

It does work if I place the hard numbers, like:

```
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vcomp ORDER BY FIELD(version_id,15, 251, 21)");
```

I tried quotes, backtick and the like without success.
Thanks

Comment: That's weird..the version you have there with double quotes should work. Try assigning the SQL query to a variable and outputting it.

Comment: Could you please do an `echo $sql` to see what it says

Comment: What error do you get when you print `mysql_error()`?

Comment: That's because it's looking like this `$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vcomp ORDER BY FIELD(version_id, "15, 251, 21")`. You can't order by `"15,251, 21"`, but you can by `15, 251, 21`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this then:

```
$ord = "version_id, ".$vid;
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vcomp ORDER BY FIELD($ord)");
```

Comment: I do not know if that's the best way around it but it did work, Thanks

Comment: @BernardA You can even add more order by field easily in `$ord` variable then messing with query statements everytime. Anyway what matters is, it worked :)